# Error 500 on return all in Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Hi I am trying to send form data using ajax to my controller in Laravel. In my controller I am trying to return $request->all() to see if the form data is present. I am getting an error 500 internal server error and I am not sure why. I have setup my `Exceptions/Handler.php` to receive errors and also checked the error log.

Here is my HTML and Ajax:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Create your post</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="post">Post</label>
      <textarea name="post" rows="8" cols="80" id="post" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="image">Add image</label>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Post" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData();
    var fileData = $('#image').prop('files')[0];
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var post = $('#post').val();

    formData.append('fileData', fileData);
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('post', post);

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url:'/post/create/create',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        formData: formData
      },

      dataType: 'json',

      success:function(response){
        toastr.success(response.response);
      },
      error: function(error){
        toastr.error(error.error)
      }
    });

  });
});


</script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
      $request->all();
      return response()->json(['responseText' => 'Success!'], 200)
}
```

Comment: Check the last error message in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I do mention in my post that I checked the logs.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the `semicolon` in your `return response()->json(['responseText' => 'Success!'], 200);` statement

Comment: Have you also checked the web servers error log? If the app hasn't loaded properly because of some parse error or similar before laravels log has initialized properly, it won't be able to save the error in the custom error log.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson where can I check the web servers error log?

Comment: @linktoahref this still doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: It depends on what web server, OS and setup you have. Google should be able to help you with that.

Comment: Add these options to your ajax, as you are sending files to the server `contentType: false, processData: false,`

Answer (score 0):

missing `;`

```
 public function create(Request $request) {
     $request->all();
     return response()->json(['responseText' => 'Success!'], 200); //<--here
}
```

Comment: @Horcrux  check the answer